# How to extend Laravel Storage facade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

Without knowing how Laravel facades work, based on my PHP knowledge, I tried to extend Storage facade to add some new functionalities.

**I have this code:**

```
class MyStorageFacade extends Facade {
    /**
     * Get the binding in the IoC container
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'MyStorage'; // the IoC binding.
    }
}
```

**While booting service provider:**

```
$this->app->bind('MyStorage',function($app){
    return new MyStorage($app);
});
```

**And facade is:**

```
class MyStorage extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage{
}
```

**When using it:**

```
use Namespace\MyStorage\MyStorageFacade as MyStorage;
MyStorage::disk('local');
```

**I get this error:**

> FatalThrowableError in Facade.php line 237: Call to undefined method Namespace\MyStorage\MyStorage::disk()

**Also** tried to extend `MyStorage` form `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem` and got the same error in other way:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method disk does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MyStorage` class needs to extend `FilesystemManager` not the Storage facade class.

```
class MyStorage extends \Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A facade is just a convenience class that will convert a static call `Facade::method` to `resolove("binding")->method` (more or less). You need to extend from Filesystem, register that in IoC, keep your facade as it is, and use the Facade as a static.

The facade:

```
class MyStorageFacade extends Facade {      
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'MyStorage'; // This one is fine
    }
}
```

Your custom storage class:

```
class MyStorage extends Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager {
}
```

In any service provider (e.g. `AppServiceProvider`)

```
$this->app->bind('MyStorage',function($app){
   return new MyStorage($app);
});
```

Then when you need to use it use it as:

```
MyStorageFacade::disk(); //Should work.
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I've tested it and get this error: `BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method disk does not exist.`

Comment: @Omid `disk` is not really defined anywhere though.

Comment: So how `\Storage::disk('local')` works in that case? @apokryfos

Comment: I think that's bound to a `FilesystemManager` class instead of a `FileSystem` class. Updated the code.

Comment: You're right, It's now working. However, it's odd that facade accessor is returning `filesystem`. @apokryfos

Comment: It's tricky. Check the source of the `Application` class at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1068 to see all built in bindings if in doubt of what a facade returns.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.. trying to figure it out for hours.. Can you please update your answer with the namespace/use and where to actually put the bind()? That would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: @emotality I was basing those on the OPs setup. At any rate I've updated it hopefully it makes more sense now